# Convert from string to system.drawing.point c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, point, typeconverter

I want to convert from string `{X=-24,Y=10}` which generated by `Point.ToString();` to Point again?

I save the string value in xml file in save mode and I want read it back to point again in read mode.

Comment: We're going to need more context. You probably *don't* want to do that, and can instead just copy the `Point`, rather than converting it to a string.

Comment: What did you try? What difficulties did you run into?

Comment: I convert it to string to save it in xml file and I need to get it back from xml file to point

Comment: How are you saving the XML? By hand? Or are you serializing?

Comment: Use the System.Drawing.PointConverter class.  Both when you serialize and deserialize.  Or just don't bother at all since xml serialization can do this automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myStringWhichCantBeChanged="{X=-24,Y=10}";
var g=Regex.Replace(myStringWhichCantBeChanged,@"[\{\}a-zA-Z=]", "").Split(',');

Point pointResult = new Point(
                  int.Parse (g[0]),
                  int.Parse( g[1]));
```

Comment: The `System.Drawing.Point` structure does not have a `Parse` method.

Comment: @oded yep . ive just noticed. gave another solution.

Comment: Just for the record, starting from .NET 3.0 there is a 'System.Drawing.Point.Parse()' function

Answer (score 2):

`System.Drawing.Point` doesn't define a `Parse` method at all - you will need to write your own that can take this format and return a `Point` structure.

`System.Windows.Point` does have a `Parse` method and may be more suitable for your needs.

However, since you are outputting to XML, non of this should be needed. You should be serializing and deserializng the object graph, which would take care of this automatically without you needing to worry about parsing and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [Point.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.parse.aspx)

```
Point pointResult = Point.Parse("-24,10");
```

Comment: I can't because the string structure for system.windows.point is different that system.drawing.point 
in system.windows.point = "10,10"
in system.drawing.point = {X=10,Y=10}

Answer (score 1):

Hans Passant had the right solution: Don't use `Point.ToString()`, which gives you that crazy, un-reusable string (MSDN calls it "[human-readable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10t2c5at.aspx)"). Use the [`PointConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.PointConverter.aspx) class instead.

To generate the string:

```
Dim myPoint As New Point(0, 0)
Dim pointConverter As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter = _
    System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(Point))
Dim pointAsString As String = pointConverter.ConvertToString(myPoint)
```

And to interpret the above string:

```
Dim pointConverter As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter = _
    System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(Point))
Dim myNewPoint As New Point = pointConverter.ConvertFromString(pointAsString)
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed this functionality today, myself, so I just coded it. Here is a very picky parser, using a "TryParse" approach. I don't like what I call 'lazy' parsing where "blah4,9anything" would get parsed as a point. And I don't like throwing errors. The 'TryParse' methods of data types are very robust to me. So here's my implementation for any to use. My only request is if you find a bug, please let me know! :)

```
public static bool TryParsePoint(string s, out System.Drawing.Point p)
{   p = new System.Drawing.Point();
    string s1 = "{X=";
    string s2 = ",Y=";
    string s3 = "}";
    int x1 = s.IndexOf(s1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    int x2 = s.IndexOf(s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    int x3 = s.IndexOf(s3, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (x1 < 0 || x1 >= x2 || x2 >= x3) { return false; }
    s1 = s.Substring(x1 + s1.Length, x2 - x1 - s1.Length);
    s2 = s.Substring(x2 + s2.Length, x3 - x2 - s2.Length); int i = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse(s1, out i) == false) { return false; } p.X = i;
    if (Int32.TryParse(s2, out i) == false) { return false; } p.Y = i;
    return true;
} // public static bool TryParsePoint(string s, out System.Drawing.Point p)
```

Note you may also want to remove or change the `public` or `static` modifier(s) of the method. But I used that method in the Program class, so mine needed to be `public static`. Suit yourself tho.

Comment: i like this too, but i second Oded's point that for XML, one should use the automatic serialization and deserialization. but when one needs a stand-alone method, i like Edward's code because it needs no other namespaces or helper functions. it stands on its own. +1

Answer (score 0):

see [PointConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) ConvertFrom method.

Answer (score 0):

try this, its what I use in my project.

```
string str = "-24,10";
Point pt = new Point(Int32.Parse(str.Split(',')[0]), Int32.Parse(str.Split(',')[1]));
```